# Open Layers 3: loading a GEBCO WMS layer

Tags: openlayers-3, wms, mapserver

I'm trying to rewrite a small outreach application made in OL2 which uses a base layer to show the ocean topography provided by the GEBCO WMS service.

When I do:

```
var gebco = new ol.layer.Image({
     source: new ol.source.TileWMS( ({
     url: 'http://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?',
     params: {'LAYERS': 'GEBCO_LATEST', 'VERSION':'1.1.1','FORMAT': 'image/png'}  }) ),
                serverType: 'mapserver'
               });
```

the layer is not added. I have looked through firebug to see
the request and while it seems to be correct the answer is a white tile with the BBOX set by Ol3. If I request directly to the map server with the BBOX [-180,-90,180,90] (or any other geographical extent) the server returns correctly the image. Then if I try to force the LayerWMS with such geographical coordinates in params:{} (i.e ..,'BBOX':'-180,-90,180,90',... ) the layer still does not load.

To show the layer I just do:

```
 mapa = new ol.Map({
     target: 'map',
     renderer:'canvas',
     layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({ 
               source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'}),
               visible: true
           })],
      view: new ol.View({
       center: ol.proj.transform([-10.0, 41.0],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857' ),
       zoom: 4
     })
  });
  mapa.addLayer(gebco);
```

I would appreciate any explanation to understand what is happening. In fact, the rest of WMS layers are added correctly, so I presume it could be related with such mapserver, but honestly I'm not very experimented with OL and map servers.

Comment: Does this service support web mercator or only EPSG:4326? Change your view projection to use EPSG:4326 and provide the center in EPSG:4326 as well in that case (so without the transform)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. If, as you indicate, I use the view projection EPSG:4326, then the layer is correctly added but now the problem is with additional satellite layers and features that are served as web mercator. So in fact I would  like to keep all in EPSG:3857. Then, how  can I load and reproject the entire gebco WMS layer to work always in 3857 ?

Comment: You will need to use software such as MapProxy to reproject it for you, since the provider of the service does not offer that projection. Or you could set up a cascading WMS with MapServer or GeoServer.

Comment: Thanks again ! I will explore these solutions.